# Crop byte array image in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, image, crop, uint8array

I am trying to crop image over UInt8 array. Here is the way I've tried:

```
func cropImageArray(byteArray: [UInt8], sourceWidth: Int32, bitsPerPixel: Int32, rect: Int32Rect) -> [UInt8] {
    var blockSize = bitsPerPixel / 8
    
    var outputPixels = [UInt8]()
    
    for _ in 0..<(rect.width * rect.height * blockSize) {
        outputPixels.append(UInt8(0.0))
    }
    
    for line in Int32(0) ..< rect.height {
        var sourceIndex = (((rect.y + line) * sourceWidth) + rect.x) * blockSize
        var destinationIndex = (line * rect.width) * blockSize
        
        for i in Int32(0) ..< Int32(rect.width * blockSize) {
            outputPixels[Int(destinationIndex + i)] = byteArray[Int(sourceIndex + i)]
        }
    }
    return outputPixels
}
```

It doesn't work properly. It gives broken image. Do you have an idea?

Edit: Here is the way I obtain byte array.

```
let img: UIImage! = UIImage(named: "example")
let d: Data! = img.pngData()
let ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: d.count)
d.withUnsafeBytes { (buff) -> Void in
        ptr.initialize(from: buff.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self).baseAddress!, count: d.count)
}
let byteArray = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: ptr, count: d.count).map({$0})
```

Edit2:
The function I've used as a [solution](https://github.com/lemberg/bottle-net/blob/a643d3ec5b0cff8de282fe6c79871c28f100c545/YOLOv3-CoreML/Shared/CVPixelBuffer%2BHelpers.swift) because of the performance is high.

Comment: how did you obtain the `byteArray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after converting to PNG, you can't just cut some bytes, thinking they are pixels, as [PNG format](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Structure.html) contains signature, and each byte is not just encoding of RGB. You have 3 options:

1. Simpler. Obtain the actual source - either CIImage or CGImage from UIImage, and crop it using [`CIImage.cropped(to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciimage/1437833-cropped) or [`CGImage.cropping(to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgimage/1454683-cropping). The linked pages contain the sample code for each. Note that UIImage will contain *either* CGImage as its source, or CIImage, never the both. Also coordinate system on CGImage and CIImage is different, so you will need to figure out the proper coordinates to crop. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56624381/5318223) someone came up with universal method it seems, but I didn't try it, so not sure if it's correct.
2. If you really want to manipulate your image on pixel level, you can use the [Accelerate framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate). It allows you to create [image buffer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/creating_and_populating_buffers_from_core_graphics_images) from CGImage (and you can always convert [CIImage to CGImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402413/getting-a-cgimage-from-ciimage) if needed). And then that buffer ([`vImage_Buffer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vimage_buffer) can be manipulated as a raw image, which is what you are trying to do above. Some examples are available [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/applying_geometric_transforms_to_images). They don't show the crop, but some close examples. Accelerate is very performant, so if you have a graphic app, may make sense to learn and use it.
3. If you really want to crop PNG image, you need to learn its format from the link I posted at the top of the answer, and then do it that way. Usually this is not a good way, since you are not getting a simplicity of the first method, or a good performance of the second.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Not especially PNG I used .pngData() method because it was giving more byte than jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0). I've tried second option you specified. The code worked on 1920*1080 image cropped 600*600 and the result is 1000 image in 160ms. Thanks a lot. I've edited the question with the implementation code link.